# How to append Ajax.ActionLink in the table body using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my ajax code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#BtnSearch").click(function () {
        var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
        var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
        var SetData = $("#DataSearching");
        SetData.html("");
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "html",
            url: "/SelectDeal/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    SetData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No Match Data</td></tr>');
                }
                else {
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                        //var clientName = item.

                        var DealDateString = item.Deal_Date;
                        var valDealDate = new Date(parseInt(DealDateString.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
                        var finalDealDate = valDealDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + valDealDate.getDate() + "/" + valDealDate.getFullYear();

                        var ValidityDateString = item.Validity_Date;
                        var valValidityDate = new Date(parseInt(ValidityDateString.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
                        var finalValidityDate = valValidityDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + valValidityDate.getDate() + "/" + valValidityDate.getFullYear();

                        var val = "<tr>" +
                       "<td>" + finalDealDate + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + item.Total_Amount_Remaining + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + item.Dealer_Name + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + finalValidityDate + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + item.Location + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + item.Deal_Amount + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" +  @Ajax.ActionLink("Recieve payment", "myAction", new AjaxOptions
                           {
                               HttpMethod = "GET",
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                               UpdateTargetId = "dialog_window_id",
                           }) +  "</td>" +
                       "</tr>";

                        SetData.append(val);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to append Ajax.ActionLink in the setData variable which is actually a `<tbody>` element. It is not working. However, If I remove @ajax.actionLink from the above code, it works perfectly fine. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the view source of the page, you can see that the current code will generate code like this

```
 "<td>" +  <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET"
```

That is invalid because it looks like we are trying to concatenate the string `"<td>"` to a variable starts like `<a` ! , hence causing the issue.

You do not need any string concatenation. Use the output rendered by your C# code(call to the `Ajax.ActionLink` method) inside the td.

The `Ajax.ActionLink` method will render markup like below where you have double quotes for the attribute values. So you should use single quotes for your string concatenation operator (to `val` variable)

`<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET"`

This should work.

```
'<td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Recieve payment", "Ajax.ActionLink", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "dialog_window_id",
    }) </td>' +
```

Comment: Will the razor compiler successfully compile @Ajax.ActionLink() when rendered from javascript?

Comment: If this code is inside a razor view, that C# expression will be executed by the server (razor view engine) and the result of that (a tag with the data attributed needed for ajaxified link behavior) will be part of the string (The js code). Check the view source of the page and you will understand. Javascript engine/browser cannot execute c# code

Comment: It is still unresponsive. What do I have to do to make it work? I have to add Action link or a button by appending it to the table row. Please help!

Comment: What you mean unresponsive ? Are you getting a console error ? Check your devtools->console

Comment: I am getting error in the following line when i debug my code in the browser: "<td>  @Ajax.ActionLink("Recieve payment", "myAction", new AjaxOptions
                               {
                                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                   UpdateTargetId = "dialog_window_id",
                               }) </td>"

Comment: How can i append the any type of action link in the table by using jquery?

Comment: "<td>  <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#dialog_window_id" href="/SelectDeal/myAction">Recieve payment</a> </td>" :This is where I am getting the error.

Comment: You missed one part in my answer. **The Ajax.ActionLink method will render markup like below where you have double quotes for the attribute values. So you should use single quotes for your string concatenation operator (to val variable)** . You should use single quotes. Read the answer (and code) carefully